# Where is the listener in the admob banner method?

Tags: android, admob

In the creation of the ad as per https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/banner, there are no intent, listener or onclick classes or methods (e.g. for buttons etc)

Is it correct to assume these functions are included in the google adView packaged method (ref. URL link)?

I'm asking because I cannot test the 'clickability' of the ads obviously..

Answer (score 1):

Below is the sample Adlistener for Admob Banner Ads

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
        // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
        // covers the screen.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
        // to the app after tapping on an ad.
    }
});
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner
[Reference](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner)